# CNN gives biased results

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, convolution

I am using a binary classifier on CNN. I have two categories "me" and "others". I have around 250 images of myself and 500 of others ( random faces db ). My current implementation of layers is very simple

```
    self.model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same', 
    input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1), padding='same'))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    self.model.add(Dense(512))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    self.model.add(Dense(2)) # for two classes
    self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

My network reaches accuracy of 93% 
[image]

[image]
My problem is the when I use this network to predict faces it always recognises any face as mine. I have cropped the faces, applied gabor filter but nothing works. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Prediction Results on Random Faces: [KK represents my face]
The probabilities are always over 97%:

```
KK identified!
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[ 0.9741978  0.0258022]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s

KK identified!
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[ 0.9897241   0.01027592]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
```

Prediction Results on my images: [KK represents my face]
The probabilities are always over 99%:

```
KK identified!
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[ 0.99639165  0.00360837]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
KK identified!
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[ 0.99527925  0.00472075]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
```

Training code

```
   def get_data(self, img_rows=IMAGE_SIZE, img_cols=IMAGE_SIZE, img_channels=3, nb_classes=2):

        images, labels = fetch_data('./data/')
        labels = np.reshape(labels, [-1])

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))
        X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))
            #train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=np.random.seed(15))

        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
            X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
            X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
            # input_shape = (3, img_rows, img_cols)
        else:
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
            X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
            X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
            # input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)

        Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
        Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(y_valid, nb_classes)
        Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

        X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
        X_valid = X_valid.astype('float32')
        X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
        X_train /= 255
        X_valid /= 255
        X_test /= 255

        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_valid = X_valid
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.Y_train = Y_train
        self.Y_valid = Y_valid
        self.Y_test = Y_test



def train_network(self, dataset, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=40, data_augmentation=True):
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.003, decay=0.0000001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    # adam = Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0001)
    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                       optimizer=sgd,
                       metrics=['accuracy'])
    if not data_augmentation:
        processed_data = self.model.fit(dataset.X_train, dataset.Y_train,
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                       validation_data=(dataset.X_valid, dataset.Y_valid),
                       shuffle=True)
    else:
        datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(
            featurewise_center=False,
            samplewise_center=False,
            featurewise_std_normalization=False,
            samplewise_std_normalization=False,
            zca_whitening=False,
            rotation_range=20,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=False)

        datagenerator.fit(dataset.X_train)

        processed_data = self.model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(dataset.X_train, dataset.Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True),
                                 samples_per_epoch=dataset.X_train.shape[0], nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=(dataset.X_valid, dataset.Y_valid))
```

Thanks

[Update: 11th June]

Layers

```
def build_model(self, dataset, nb_classes=2):
        self.model = Sequential()

        self.model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        self.model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same'))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(512))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        self.model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
        self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))

        self.model.summary()
```

Data augmentation

```
    # this will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,             # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,              # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,   # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,                  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=20,                     # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.2,                # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.2,               # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        # rescale=1. / 255,
        # shear_range=0.2,
        # zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,                 # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)                  # randomly flip images

    datagen.fit(dataset.X_train)

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(self.FILE_PATH, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callback_list = [checkpoint]

    # fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow()
    train_generator = datagen.flow(dataset.X_train, dataset.Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    history = self.model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                       samples_per_epoch=dataset.X_train.shape[0],
                                       nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                                       validation_data=(dataset.X_valid, dataset.Y_valid),
                                       callbacks=callback_list)
```

Dataset

```
class DataSet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.X_train = None
        self.X_valid = None
        self.X_test = None
        self.Y_train = None
        self.Y_valid = None
        self.Y_test = None

    # support only binary classification for now, thus 2 class limit
    def get_data(self, img_rows=IMAGE_SIZE, img_cols=IMAGE_SIZE, img_channels=3, nb_classes=2):

        images, labels = fetch_data('./data/')
        labels = np.reshape(labels, [-1])

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))

        X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))

        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
            X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
            X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)

        else:
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
            X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
            X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)


        # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
        Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
        Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(y_valid, nb_classes)
        Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

        X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
        X_valid = X_valid.astype('float32')
        X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
        X_train /= 255
        X_valid /= 255
        X_test /= 255

        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_valid = X_valid
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.Y_train = Y_train
        self.Y_valid = Y_valid
        self.Y_test = Y_test
```

Comment: This seems odd, do you have a separate set of data for testing (not used for training).

Comment: yes, I am using separate images. I also have a separate script which fetches face from webcamera and feeds it to the prediction method, still the results are biased. I have seen network to be biased if certain class has significantly more images than the others, but here my images are half the number of random people. Still it predict 'me' on every image.

Comment: Did you check the output in probability, like is the network 90% sure it's you or it's 51% it's you.

Comment: its always over 97% that its me. I have updated question with further details.

Comment: What is the rate when you give your own images?

Comment: Its over 99%. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Are you sure your training data is correct ??

Comment: Well, training data is simple actually. two dirs one with my pictures and other with random faces. I assign 0 to my pictures and 1 to other pictures. `labels = np.array([0 if label.endswith('kk_pics') else 1 for label in labels])`

Comment: Is this generating an actual tuple? `input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]`

Comment: This is just to provide the shape of the images to the keras input layer. Its mandatory thing for first layer in keras. in my case `dataset.X_train.shape=(338, 128, 128, 3)` and thus `input_shape=(128, 128, 3)`.

Comment: I know that. What I ask is: is that code generating an actual tuple? I've seen examples that didn't work with lists.

Comment: Which `loss` and `optimizer` are you using? Could you provide us a full training script?

Comment: "CNN gives biased results" You don't say.

Answer (score 5):

The result is not odd at all. The network has never learnt what makes your face special, but just remembered what makes the 500 set different from yours. Once you present a new face, it has no "memory" of it, and therefore interprets it as yours, just because none of features present in the 500 faces appears in the 501th.

Some ideas how to tackle this:

- Augment your data with [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), as proposed by petezurich.
- Increase your kernel size. 2*2 is too tiny to catch facial features. Consider 3*3, or even stacking two 3*3 in the first hidden layer.
- Consider using Batch Normalization and regularization. Increase Dropout to 0.5.
- Consider replacing pooling layers with [diluted convolutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07122) (available in Keras).
- Make sure you normalise your input data.
- Lower the number of feature maps (filters) in the first layer. Consider using e.g. 32 3*3 maps instead of 128 tiny elements (these are your main problem if I am to guess). This way you will force the network to generalise instead of learning some tiny nuances.

A nice test for my hypothesis from the last point would be to visualise the activations in hidden layers, especially the first hidden layer. I have a feeling your network activates on some irrelevant features (or rather - noise), rather than "human features" (like eyes, haircut).

[EDIT after more code has been added]

- Centre your input data around zero.
- Lower the batch size. With so few examples you don't want too much of averaging in a batch.

I still think that using e.g. 16 or 32 filters in the first hidden layer should be the first thing to check. Look at your face. Can you spot 128 "features"? Unless you have some severe acne, I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Whatever you pointed out make lot of sense. I increased the kernel size to 3x3, set input mean to 0, reduced the filter size, and lowered the batch size. However, now the accuracy doesnt go beyond 78%. I have also added new images in both categories, but no difference. I have updated the question with new code.

Comment: At the moment, I am training the network again by reducing the batch size to 8 and samples_per_epoch value in fit_generator as `dataset.X_train.shape[0]*batch_size`. Thus, now there are 343 samples per epoch. I read it somewhere this might be useful, thus trying it out.

Comment: I also used https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis on the previous model ( on which you gave your comments ) to generate attention map of an image at the last dense layer and it was sparse. So, may be that in sync with the filter size point of yours.

Comment: "even stacking two 3*3 in the first hidden layer." I am not sure how i can stack two kernels in a layer, can you give an example, if possible.

Comment: Stacking CNNs:
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')
The latter is has effective receptive field 5 * 5

Comment: Based on the latest results (78%) I think we reached a great improvement over the original results, where it was recognising any face as your face. I'd appreciate if we were not making the question "a moving target" to get best achievable score (whatever that could be). Mind that you might have some bias in the data that can be discovered only after screening the data. Also, I'd consider alternative approaches, like using algos from OpenCV. Last but not least, mind that neural networks are easily fooled (e.g. http://karpathy.github.io/2015/03/30/breaking-convnets/)

Answer (score 2):

For a classification task like that you don´t have enough data with 250 + 500 samples. And a 50/100 relation between class A (you) vs class B (others) is a substantial bias. At least you should try to equalize that with the class_weight parameter in the .fit() function while training.

A better approach would be to retrain an existing ConvNet like VGG16 or Inception from Keras applications: https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

You easily could increase your number of samples with data augmentation (see ImageDataGenerator here https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

In order to analyze your code you need to show how you split your data and how you train it. The right way of training is splitting in train data and validation data and than evaluate on another set of separate test data, that the network never has seen and you haven´t optimized your hyperparameters with.

As far as i can see from your comment regarding your train/test/validation split: Do you split two times from the same set of images? That gives you probably the same images in validation and test data, which in turn would lead to wrong results.

And to see your code for training would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information. For the substantial bias case, I would have expected the network to be more biased towards 'not me' as number of random faces are twice as mine. Regarding the spilting of data I am using it as: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))
        X_valid, X_test, y_valid, y_test = \
            train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=random.randint(0, 100))`

Comment: ImageGenerator: `datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                featurewise_center=False, 
                samplewise_center=False,  
                featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                samplewise_std_normalization=False,
                zca_whitening=False,
                rotation_range=20,
                width_shift_range=0.2,
                height_shift_range=0.2,
vertically (fraction of total height)
                horizontal_flip=True, 
                vertical_flip=False)  `

Comment: Have you normalized your data in anyway? Either training or testing data?